# How to convert an object to an integer in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following query in Laravel :

```
           $cat_get = DB::table('aimcats as a')
                    ->join('subcat as s', 's.cat_id', '=' , 'a.id')
                    ->where('s.id', $subcat)         
                    ->select('a.id as categ_id')                   
                    ->first();
```

The vardump for $cat_get is this :

```
object(stdClass)#392 (1) { ["categ_id"]=> int(502) }
```

I need to change the 502 to a number without the object to be able to save it in the database.

As of now I'm receiving this error

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Comment: $cat-get->categ_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will help you:

```
$dataToSave = new YourClass;
$dataToSave->categ_id = $cat_get->categ_id;
$dataToSave->save();
```